# Assigning CSS style to variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a simple JavaScript function that takes a td (table cell) and either gives it a red border style or turns this off. The code is:

```
function doStuff(theCell) 
{
    var highlight = "2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    if(borderStyle==highlight)
    {
        theCell.style.border="";
    }
    else
    {
        theCell.style.border=highlight;
    }
}
```

This works fine. However to try to make the code cleaner I tried to replace the css border style by a variable (declared just below the first one):

```
var borderStyle = theCell.style.border;
```

This works OK when I use it in the equality comparison, but not when I put it in the style assignation in the ‘else’ clause.

I must be trying to do something very foolish. Could anyone explain.

Comment: Where have you defined borderStyle in your function?

Comment: `theCell.style.border` returns a `string`, later in `else` block, you are just updating string, not assigning it back to element..

Comment: *I must be trying to do something very foolish.* You're assuming that assignment to `borderStyle` assigns *a reference*, and that changes made to `borderStyle` will impact `theCell.style.border`. This assumption is false.

Comment: You really ought to apply a class to the `<td>` instead of setting the border style directly. Ask yourself, for example ... _Why_ is the border red? Is it because the value is negative? Then assign a class _"negative"_ as in `<td class="negative">` — in plain javascript this can be `theCell.classList.add('negative');` and `theCell.classList.remove('negative')` to get rid of it. Then define CSS `td.negative { border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); }` ... now you don't have to change code to re-style.

Comment: Thanks @StephenP. I've done that. I assume your 'theCell.classList.add()' and 'theCell.classList.remove()' code is to allow multiple classes on an HTML element. I've used  'theCell.className=' to make the change instead.

Comment: Yes @David and there is also `toggle()` — see MDN [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). `className` is supported everywhere, but `classList` is everywhere _except_ IE before 10 ... but there are shims (I use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) for most of the basics). _jQuery_ also has a cross-browser way to do this, if you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript does not create reference to the object if you write code such as `var borderStyle = theCell.style.border;`. Here a copy of only the value of border is assigned to borderStyle. The object which is `theCell` remained unharmed at its place. No reference is created to it.

Comment: Thanks, and also to those that commented. My face is as red as the border on my table cells (when I code them right, that is).